# How can I get the ID of the comment with the oldest date and the most number of like in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to queries. I have a commenting system with likes. What I want to do is get the ID of the oldest comment with the most likes.

This is my table.

```
CREATE TABLE `wallcomments` (
  `c_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comments` text NOT NULL,
  `date_created` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `for_image` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'no=post, yes=imagePoPup',
  `clikes` mediumint(6) NOT NULL,
  `uip` char(30) NOT NULL,
  `tagedpersons` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `comment_image` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This is my PHP function**strong text**.

```
public function GetMostLovedComments($CommentPostID) 
{
    global $DBConnection;

    $cond = '';
    $cond = " AND wallcomments.parent_id = 0"; // only selects comments and not replies

    $query_pc = "SELECT c_id, MAX(clikes) AS max
                FROM wallcomments
                WHERE post_id = '.$CommentPostID. $cond .'"; 

    $result_pc = mysqli_query($DBConnection, $query_pc);
    $row_pc = mysqli_fetch_array($result_pc);
    $most_likes = $row_pc['max'];
    $cc_id = $row_pc['c_id'];

    $query = "SELECT date_created, MAX(date_created) AS min
                FROM wallcomments
                WHERE post_id = '.$CommentPostID. $cond .'";

    $result = mysqli_query($DBConnection, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $oldest_c = $row['min'];

    $query3 = "SELECT c_id
                FROM wallcomments
                WHERE date_created = '.$oldest_c'";

    $result3 = mysqli_query($DBConnection, $query3);
    $row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3);
    $com_id = $row3['c_id'];

    return  $oldest_c;
}
```

Comment: so do you want the one with the highest # of likes and if tied, use the oldest date... or do you want the oldest dates and if tied, grab the one with the highest likes?  What you can't do is get the one with the most likes if it's not the oldest, which is what I think you are asking for.

Comment: You are going to have to select a range for most likes like oldest comment with 100 or more likes.

Comment: and max(date_created) returns NEWEST one, not the oldest...  perhaps you want min(date_Created) as min.

Comment: Well at first I was just getting the ID of the most liked comment. But then I kept having some comments that tied. But I only need one comment to be chosen at a time so I decided to include the date as well as a second parameter or check. I was thinking that since there can only be one unique date and time. That should eliminate the chances of any ties. So I want to check the number of likes and the date created so that I can narrow it down to only one.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean...

Return the C_ID of the wallcomment with the oldest date and when tied return the one with the higest clikes

```
SELECT wc.c_id 
FROM wallcomments wc
INNER JOIN (SELECT min(date_created) MDC
            FROM wallcomments
            WHERE post_id = YourConditionVariable) wc2
 on WC.date_created = wc2.mdc
WHERE post_id = YourConditionVariable
ORDER BY clikes desc
LIMIT 1
```

Return the C_ID of the wallcomment with the most clikes when tied return the one with the oldest date_created

```
SELECT wc.c_id 
FROM wallcomments wc
INNER JOIN (SELECT max(clikes) MDC
            FROM wallcomments
            WHERE post_id = YourConditionVariable) wc2
 on WC.clikes = wc2.mdc
WHERE post_id = YourConditionVariable
ORDER BY date_created asc
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer xQbert, I tried your code but the function only returns "1"... I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: by "1" do you mean 1 record? that's what the limit does it only returns 1 record.  or is it only returning the wc.C_ID of "1" for both?  I guess I don't know what you're trying to accomplish yet.

Comment: My apologies, the second code worked for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: But now I want to add a WHERE clause so that it only queries the comments for the posts and not all comments.

Comment: The where clause simply needs to be added to the inner query.

Comment: How can I add this piece of code to the query?  "  WHERE post_id = '.$CommentPostID. $cond .'";  "

Comment: Seems odd to me that post_Id would define the type of post but... just add it in the subquery. (updated above)  you may need to add it to both places actually...  The inner query ensures you get the right max likes comment, but as you could tie with another one not of the type desired, you have to limit the outer query as well.

Comment: Okay now it's not returning anything after I've added the Where clauses. I think it would be more efficient to do this.

Comment: Return the C_ID of the wallcomment with the most clikes when tied return the one with the smallest C_ID number. How would I go about creating that Query including the Where Clause?

Comment: Should I be returning "wc.c_id " or simply "c_id"?

Comment: Never mind I got it to work. Thank you so much. If I could up vote your answer then I would but it won't let me.